# Spring Data MongoDB: How to describe aggregation $merge with Spring Aggregation?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Code that I want to execute by `MongoTemplate`:

```
{
    $merge: {
        into: 'someCollection',
        on: "_id",
        whenMatched: 'merge',
        whenNotMatched: 'discard'
    }
}
```

I did not find any suitable methods that allow me to describe `$merge` stage, have doubts if `Spring Data MongoDB` even supports this stage?

Comment: Yes it is!
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/MergeOperation.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `Spring Data MongoDB` have support for `$merge` stage.
Your code can be executed by `MongoTemplate` following way.

```
MergeOperation mergeOperation = Aggregation.merge()
        .intoCollection("someCollection")
        .on("_id")
        .whenMatched(MergeOperation.WhenDocumentsMatch.mergeDocuments())
        .whenNotMatched(MergeOperation.WhenDocumentsDontMatch.discardDocument())
        .build();
```

Use this `mergeOperation` with `mongoTemplate`.