# Can Reactive Mongo Template execute MergeOperation?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I want to know if it is possible to execute `MergeOperation` snippet:

```java
MergeOperation mergeOperation = Aggregation.merge()
        .intoCollection("someCollection")
        .on("_id")
        .whenMatched(MergeOperation.WhenDocumentsMatch.mergeDocuments())
        .whenNotMatched(MergeOperation.WhenDocumentsDontMatch.discardDocument())
        .build();
```

with the `ReactiveMongoTemplate`. Like what specified in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66164747/spring-data-mongodb-how-to-describe-aggregation-merge-with-spring-aggregation/66171963#66171963), but with reactive streams.